# Auto Cropping responsive Background Image

Tags: css, web, responsive-design, coding-style

Looking to set a background image that resizes for the height will fill without repeating, but will somehow crop the width to lock aspect ratio. I'm at a loss guys, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I may have answered my own question! I set background size to cover, and background position to center. keeps the image centered and stretches height accordingly